# Query the nested documents inside mongodb arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When updating Mongo db I want to update a document inside multiple nested arrays. But none of my querys worked when tried to update it. Below is the of existing table:

```
     Array
   (
   [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 5ce268ef6803fa8f237b23c6
                )


        [member_number] => 26b091bdd3f9505b2103a187f3ac6643
        [member_forename] => 1d40521662cc484d7c06992c61303ba6
        [member_surname] => 581c78bf6fe11cc0ff53a805a100d441


        [certificates] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [member_id] => MongoId Object
                            (
                                [$id] => 5ce268ef6803fa8f237b23c6
                            )

                        [certificate_id] => MongoId Object
                            (
                                [$id] => 5ce4dd3d6803fa15454cbed5
                            )

                        [skills_completed] => N
                        [certificate_issued] => N
                        [details] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [member_id] => MongoId Object
                                            (
                                                [$id] => 5ce268ef6803fa8f237b23c6
                                            )

                                        [session_id] => MongoId Object
                                            (
                                                [$id] => 5ce4f1a96803fa574e4cbede
                                            )

                                        [mark_status] => A
                                        [cd_status] => A
                                        [gradeId] => MongoId Object
                                            (
                                                [$id] => 5ca48ccfa36f74db9a8a0620
                                            )

                                        [gradeKey] => NP
                                        [achieved_date] => MongoDate Object
                                            (
                                                [sec] => 1558531565
                                                [usec] => 713000
                                            )

                                        [detail_id] => MongoId Object
                                            (
                                                [$id] => 5ce4dd526803fa1f454cbed7
                                            )

                                        [marked_by] => MongoId Object
                                            (
                                                [$id] => 5cb5622a6803fa640b7b23c7
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [certificate_issued_by] => 
                        [certificate_session_id] => 
                        [sc_date] => 
                    )




        [updated_at] => MongoDate Object
            (
                [sec] => 1558341930
                [usec] => 482000
            )

    )
```

)

I want to update one of the details section that is nested inside certificates.the certificate array is inside member table.

my matching condition is _id = member id ,
certificates.certificate_id=xxxx,

certificates.details.detail_id=xxxx

I have the full array that will replace zeroth position of details array.how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are embedded associations involved, letting Mongoid do the work should be straightforward:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :bars
end

class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :thing
  embedded_in :foo
end

class Thing
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :bar
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bars = [Bar.new, Bar.new]
foo.save!

foo.bars[0].thing = Thing.new
foo.save!

foo.reload
foo.bars.map(&:thing)
# => [#<Thing _id: 5ce85f47026d7c20c4c0613a, bar_id: BSON::ObjectId('5ce85f47026d7c20c4c06138')>, nil]
```

Take note of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-2951 - in the above example I  changed a field of one of the Bar instances but I did not modify the list of Bars.